# Kotlin Data class v/s open class?

Tags: java, kotlin, model, realm, data-class

As I am converting my java project to kotlin project, I came
to know about data classes in kotlin(replacement of Java model classes).

Now I have a requirement for my `kotlin data class` to support `RealmObject` but as per the link 
[Kotlin data class of RealmObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368374/kotlin-data-class-of-realmobject), it says data classes are apparently not supported in Realm, so I need to make my `data class` as `open class`.

So basically, I want to know the difference between these two terms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Data** classes are intended to hold values. In the Java Bean sense, their main purpose is to wrap around some set of values.

What makes Java beans really ugly is that many important methods, such as `equals()`, `hashcode()` or `toString()` that *ideally* should know about the fields of your class ... are inherited from java.lang.Object. And thus they do nothing useful.

When you declare a `data class` in Kotlin, the Kotlin compiler simply **adds** a reasonable implementation for all these methods. See [kotlin-lang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html):

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all
> properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> - equals()/hashCode() pair;
> - toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)";

In other words: when that User class is a data class, and when you have **two**
users objects declared with `User(name=John, age=42)`, then those two objects will be equal, because the *generated* `equals()` method will compare the name and age within those data class objects.

An **Open** class on the other hand, is an ordinary class that is **open** for extension. Meaning: by default, when you write a class in Kotlin, it can **not** be extended. Yes, inheritance is **prevented** by default. By declaring a class to be open, you tell the compiler: "I intend to extend this class". In other words: if you want to have `Child extends Base`, then your `Base` class must be declared **open** in Kotlin.

In short: **data** classes are meant as *containers for values*, that can be used as that. **Open** is a different concept, it simply boils down to: can be inherited (respectively overridden when talking about methods) by some child class.

Long story short: in that question you are linking to, you are told:

- you can't use Realm to process **data** classes
- and the example given there simply *assumes* that maybe you want to extend that Person class, so it is declared `open`

I guess: unless you intend to create subclasses of your classes, you simply go **without** the open keyword! Write standard kotlin, and make them open if they are intended to be extended.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin Data Class:

One of the many handy features that the Kotlin language offers is the data keyword. When we declare a class with the data keyword the compiler implements the equals(Object o), hashCode(), and toString() methods, thus saving us from the trouble to do it manually.

Kotlin Open Class:

In Kotlin, all the classes are final by default i.e. they can’t be inherited by default. In Java, you have to make your class final explicitly. So, to make a class inheritable to the other classes, you must mark it with the open keyword otherwise you will get an error saying “type is final so can’t be inherited”.

In summary, data classes are best used for classes whose main purpose is to hold data, while open classes are used when you need to allow the class to be extended by other classes. If you need to use RealmObject in your Kotlin class, you'll need to use an open class instead of a data class.

Comment: Below answer is mine I've deleted that account.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Data Class**:

One of the many handy features that the Kotlin language offers is the **data** keyword. When we declare a class with the **data** keyword the compiler implements the equals(Object o), hashCode(), and toString() methods, thus saving us from the trouble to do it manually.

**Kotlin Open Class**:

In Kotlin, all the classes are **final** by default i.e. they can’t be *inherited* by default. In Java, you have to make your class final explicitly. So, to *make a class inheritable* to the other classes, you must mark it with the **open** keyword otherwise you will get an error saying “type is final so can’t be inherited”.