# Only concrete Realm classes are allowed in RealmLists. Neither interfaces nor abstract classes are allowed

Tags: kotlin, realm, data-class

I am trying to convert my `kotlin-data-class` into `Realm supported model class` but getting the above error.

I have followed this below link to convert my data class into realm supported class 
[Kotlin data class of RealmObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368374/kotlin-data-class-of-realmobject)

This error has come because of my model class contains `RealmList<Any>` and As I am using `JSON to Kotlin class plugin` for converting my JSON object to the corresponding kotlin data class(which has converted it to List type)

Below is my Realm kotlin class

```
open class View :RealmObject() {
    var alignment: String?=null
    var bg_color: String?=null
    var company_id: String?=null
    var group_title_text: GroupTitleText?=null
    var layout: String?=null
    var questions: RealmList<Any>?=null
    var screen_id: String?=null
    var survey_id: String?=null
    var title: String?=null
}
```

Please help me find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `RealmList<Any>?=null` you need to use a real RealmObject instead of `Any`

Comment: Using var questions: RealmList<RealmObject>?=null, still give me  error: package io.realm.io_realm_RealmObjectRealmProxy does not exist

Comment: I said *real* realm object, like `View` in your case, etc